# FSharpList assertions with NFluent?

Tags: f#, xunit, nfluent

I read on the [nfluent documentation](http://n-fluent.net/) that you can assert lists like this:

```cs
var inteers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 666 };
Check.That(integers).Contains(3, 5, 666);
```

But when I try this in F# I cannot seem to get it work:

```ml
let myList : int list = [1;2;3]
Check.That(events).Contains(1, 2, 3)
```

The error message is seen here:

[image]

How do I get the list assertions to work i F#?

**Update**

In my actual code the F# function returns an `FSharpList` and I don't want to change this so I cannot simple change the type to e.g. a `seq`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F# doesn't do implicit casting like C# does. Method signature expects to have IEnumerable, but you supply a list. That's what the error say.
The easiest fix would be to create a sequence, that is same as IEnumerable in C#:

```
let myList : int list = [1;2;3]
let mySeq = list |> Seq.ofList
Check.That(mySeq).Contains(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Thank you, however in my actual code the F# function returns an FSharpList and I don't want to change this so I cannot simple change the type to seq. I've updated the question. Is the correct way then to convert the FSharpList to a seq?

Comment: Then use [Seq.ofList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.oflist%5b%27t%5d-function-%5bfsharp%5d) to do the conversion.

Comment: Or you can do explicit cast using `:>` operator. `let mySeq = list :> int seq`